# GUI in a Multi Browser Environment with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to code a multi browser GUI test. But I'm getting a NullPointerException in

```
driver.quit();
```

and

```
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/Params/ClientCutOff/index.jsp?lang=en");
```

here's my code

```
public class CrossBrowserTest {
public WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private final StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int browser = i;

        if (browser == 0) {
            System.out.println("Running Firefox");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        else if (browser == 1) {
            System.out.println("Running Internet Explorer");
            DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities
                    .internetExplorer();
            ieCapabilities
                    .setCapability(
                            InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                            true);
            File file = new File(
                    "C:/tools/Selenium/IEDriverServer_x64_2.47.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    file.getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
            baseUrl = "http://isisetet:8081/";
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testAccess() throws Exception {
    // Test If the screen is acessible
    System.out.println("Test if the screen is accessible");
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/Params/ClientCutOff/index.jsp?lang=en");
    assertTrue(driver.getTitle().matches("^[\\s\\S]*ClientCutOff$"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
        } else {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
        return alertText;
    } finally {
        acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
}
```

the test works in either mozilla or IE alone, I'm just trying to make it run in both browsers one after the other

Comment: Just Curious what is the <class name="package.classname" /> ?  Have you mentioned the actual values ?

Comment: even with the correct class name, package.ClientCutOffMulti.CrossBrowserTest, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are

> getting a NullPointerException

because of the session issues (especially  if you deal with `driver.getWindowHandle();` code). Use `driver.close();` to close a single browser window and `driver.quit();` to end the whole session. The second place with the `driver.get("...");` could be cause by the same - driver can't switch to the next browser (session).